# Efficient Method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi How can use a method several times without repeating and making another method in JavaScript.Cause what I did is that I made a method with the same fields and code but only difference is the id. I need one parameter for each method which would be the id.

```
function enemyGet() {

    new enemyMove2()
    new enemyMove()
    new enemyMove3()
}

  function enemyMove2() {

    var enemyimage = document.getElementById("enemy");
        var leftenemy = parseInt(enemyimage.style.left);
        var topenemy = parseInt(enemyimage.style.top);
        var time = setTimeout("enemyMove2()", 20)

        if (leftenemy < leftplayer) {
            leftenemy = leftenemy + 5;

        }
        if (leftenemy > leftplayer) {
            leftenemy = leftenemy - 5;

        }

        if (topenemy < topplayer) {
            topenemy = topenemy + 5;
        }
        if (topenemy > topplayer) {
            topenemy = topenemy - 5;
        }

        enemyimage.style.left = leftenemy + "px";
        enemyimage.style.top = topenemy + "px";

        var hit_list = $("#x").collision(".lollol");
        hit_list.remove();

}

function enemyMove() {


    var enemyimage = document.getElementById("enemy2");
    var leftenemy = parseInt(enemyimage.style.left);
    var topenemy = parseInt(enemyimage.style.top);
    var time = setTimeout("enemyMove()", 20)

    if (leftenemy < leftplayer) {
        leftenemy = leftenemy + 5;

    }
    if (leftenemy > leftplayer) {
        leftenemy = leftenemy - 5;

    }

    if (topenemy < topplayer) {
        topenemy = topenemy + 5;
    }
    if (topenemy > topplayer) {
        topenemy = topenemy - 5;
    }

    enemyimage.style.left = leftenemy + "px";
    enemyimage.style.top = topenemy + "px";

    var hit_list = $("#x").collision(".lollol");
    hit_list.remove();

}

function enemyMove3() {


    var enemyimage = document.getElementById("enemy3");
    var leftenemy = parseInt(enemyimage.style.left);
    var topenemy = parseInt(enemyimage.style.top);
    var time = setTimeout("enemyMove3()", 20)

    if (leftenemy < leftplayer) {
        leftenemy = leftenemy + 5;

    }
    if (leftenemy > leftplayer) {
        leftenemy = leftenemy - 5;

    }

    if (topenemy < topplayer) {
        topenemy = topenemy + 5;
    }
    if (topenemy > topplayer) {
        topenemy = topenemy - 5;
    }

    enemyimage.style.left = leftenemy + "px";
    enemyimage.style.top = topenemy + "px";

    var hit_list = $("#x").collision(".lollol");
    hit_list.remove();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a parameter:

```
function enemyGet() {
    // pass the id as a argument to the function
    enemyMove("enemy2")
    enemyMove("enemy")
    enemyMove("enemy3")
}

function enemyMove(enemy) {
    // the variable enemy is the id passed as an argument to the function 
    var enemyimage = document.getElementById(enemy);
        var leftenemy = parseInt(enemyimage.style.left);
        var topenemy = parseInt(enemyimage.style.top);
        // Pass the parameter in timeout as well. You have access to enemy variable due to concept of closure
        var time = setTimeout(function(){enemyMove(enemy)}, 20)

        if (leftenemy < leftplayer) {
            leftenemy = leftenemy + 5;

        }
        if (leftenemy > leftplayer) {
            leftenemy = leftenemy - 5;

        }

        if (topenemy < topplayer) {
            topenemy = topenemy + 5;
        }
        if (topenemy > topplayer) {
            topenemy = topenemy - 5;
        }

        enemyimage.style.left = leftenemy + "px";
        enemyimage.style.top = topenemy + "px";

        var hit_list = $("#x").collision(".lollol");
        hit_list.remove();

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use just one method but has different id?

Comment: Yup. You are passing the id as an argument to the function

Comment: Any reason why you're using `new` to call the functions?

Comment: to stop the timer you will need to call setTimeout ONLY if there is no collision. i.e based on the value of hit_list

Comment: @BasaratAli Ahh okay, I didn't know if I was missing/forgetting something :)

Comment: @BasaratAli I didn't realize the `new` was in the OP :)

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this you can parameterize the value varying between calls.

You can pass the varying `id` as a parameter to the `enemyMove` method.

```
function enemyMove(id) {


    var enemyimage = document.getElementById(id);
    var leftenemy = parseInt(enemyimage.style.left);
    var topenemy = parseInt(enemyimage.style.top);
    var time = setTimeout(function(){
        enemyMove(id);
    }, 20)

    if (leftenemy < leftplayer) {
        leftenemy = leftenemy + 5;

    }
    if (leftenemy > leftplayer) {
        leftenemy = leftenemy - 5;

    }

    if (topenemy < topplayer) {
        topenemy = topenemy + 5;
    }
    if (topenemy > topplayer) {
        topenemy = topenemy - 5;
    }

    enemyimage.style.left = leftenemy + "px";
    enemyimage.style.top = topenemy + "px";

    var hit_list = $("#x").collision(".lollol");
    hit_list.remove();

}
```

Then

```
function enemyGet() {

    new enemyMove('enemy')
    new enemyMove('enemy2')
    new enemyMove('enemy3')
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use just one method but has different id?

Comment: yea thats my problem as well.. but is there any way to keep it moving?

Comment: @user2242573 Not you, I meant ArunPJohny. The `setTimeout` doesn't pass a parameter - that's a problem

Answer (score -1):

You can use square bracket notation to reference the function:

```
// Store reference to global object for use wherever
var global = this;

...
  var n = 3;

  // Call method based on value of n
  global['enemyMove' + n]();
```

...

You might make your functions properties (methods) of some object other than the global/window object.